# How to properly use SPServiceApplicationCollection?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to write a little console app to display a list of running Service Applications on a SharePoint 2010 site.  I have employed Microsoft.SharePoint as well as Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration, but so far I am not having much luck.  Below is what I have been fiddling around with.  Can anyone give me some pointers on how to properly use SPServiceApplicationCollection?

Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SPServiceApplicationCollection services = new      SPServiceApplicationCollection(String, SPFarm.Local.Services);
        foreach (SPServiceApplication service in services)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(service.Name);

            if (service is SPWebService)
            {
                SPWebService webService = (SPWebService)service;

                foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webService.WebApplications)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(webApp.Name);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**
After some digging/asking around I came up with a rough solution of what I wanted.
For future reference/anyone else that wishes to do this sort of thing,  I was able to get a list of deployed servers as well as the application name by doing the following:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ServiceProcess;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Health;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var solution = SPFarm.Local.Solutions["Your Service Application Name.wsp"];
        string serverName = string.Empty;
        foreach (SPServer server in solution.DeployedServers)
        {
            serverName += server.Name;
            Console.WriteLine(server.Name);
        }

        if (solution != null)
        {
            if (solution.Deployed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is currently deployed on: {1}", solution.Name, serverName);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error!  Solution not deployed!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: As an update, it turns out what I want to be using is actually

    SPFarm.Local.Solutions

Comment: If you have found an answer to your question, write it in the answer box and mark it as the Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging/asking around I came up with a rough solution of what I wanted. For future reference/anyone else that wishes to do this sort of thing, I was able to get a list of deployed servers as well as the application name by doing the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Health;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var solution = SPFarm.Local.Solutions["Your Service Application Name.wsp"];
    string serverName = string.Empty;
    foreach (SPServer server in solution.DeployedServers)
    {
        serverName += server.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(server.Name);
    }

    if (solution != null)
    {
        if (solution.Deployed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is currently deployed on: {1}", solution.Name, serverName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!  Solution not deployed!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
  }
 }
}
```